# How to pass password to sqlcipher ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, password-protection, sqlcipher

I'm trying to implement a secure database in my app that requires users to enter a password when the app is launched. The password that they enter is used to decrypt the sqlcipher database that contains their data. The part that I am stumped on is how to pass the password to the content provider.

Right now I am storing the password temporarily in shared preferences for my contentprovider to access it and then deleting the sharedpreference when onStop is called in my MainActivity. However, this seems overly complicated once I introduce multiple activities. Is there a more efficient way to set the password for my sqlcipher ContentProvider just for the current app session?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time and go through the tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. It is also very important that before you post your question, you first do some searching - and indicate what you have tried on your on so far. This gives members of the community some ideas of which solutions you have already explored.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The part that I am stumped on is how to pass the password to the content provider.

Option #1: Do not use a `ContentProvider`.

Option #2: Use `call()` on a `ContentResolver`, which in turn invokes `call()` on your `ContentProvider`. This is an ad-hoc communications path, where you define basically what the meaning is. You can use this as a "set passphrase" sort of mechanism, where your UI layer collects the passphrase and delivers it to the provider via `call()`. Note that this requires a `minSdkVersion` of 11 or higher.

Of the two, I strongly recommend Option #1.

> Right now I am storing the password temporarily in shared preferences for my contentprovider to access it and then deleting the sharedpreference when onStop is called in my MainActivity.

That writes the passphrase to disk, in cleartext. **Please do not do this**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! If I go down the path of not using a `ContentProvider`, would you recommend converting my current `ContentProvider` class into a Utility class to avoid writing database calls in my fragments?

Comment: @DillonConnolly: That's difficult to answer in the abstract. Some people put that code on the `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Some have a utility class. Those using an ORM often have neither, as the ORM more or less fills that role. The key in your case is that you set yourself up to be able to open the database when you get the passphrase and safely ensure that you don't try using the database before that point.